# Problem passing props to a React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a webpage where I make a fetch to my api and get the result, I parse that result to get an actual array with 40 countries and then with a forEach I deal with this info this way:

```
let position = 1

data.countries.forEach(el=>{
    console.log(position)
    setCountryList(tmpCountry => [...tmpCountry, <VisitedCountry position={position}/>])    
    position++
})
```

I have that **{countryList}** on my return and the child components are being rendered properly but the problem I have is that the `console.log()` of the `forEach` shows the right values from 1 to 40 but when I show that info from the child component, all of them are getting the last value (40). This is the basic code I have in my child component:

```
const VisitedCountry = ({position}) => {
    console.log(position)
    return (
        <h1>{position}</h1>
    )
}
export default VisitedCountry
```

That `console.log()` in line 2 is always showing 40.

I tried with `useState()` and even updating the variable within an useEffect applied to {countryList} but I´m getting the same result.

I guess this is more a how-js-works instead of a proper React problem, but anyway, I´m not being able to fix this. How should I handle something like this?

Comment: I suspect you can just create a local variable inside the `forEach` callback and store the value of `position` in that variable to use in the component, so each component references its own value instead of all of them referencing the same variable.  But honestly I'd take a step back in the design overall and not store component instances in state in the first place.

Comment: React batches `setState` to the end and I suspect it's getting the final value of position when it happens.  Regardless, you can just set the state *once* explicitly.  I would use `setCountryList(data.countries.map((el, position) => <VisitedCountry position={position+1}/>)`

Comment: Thanks @David. I made that step back as you also commented, now I just need to get used to do it this way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store the `VisitedCountry` components in a state.

It's probably way easier to just `map()` over the `data` array and then render each `VisitedCountry` as is.

Then you can use the iterator of the `map()` to set the `position` as needed.

---

Small demo:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const VisitedCountry = ({position}) => {
    console.log(position)
    return (
        <h1>{position}</h1>
    )
}

const Example = () => {
    
    const fakeDataCountries = [
      'USA', 'UK', 'BE'
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            {fakeDataCountries.map((c, i) => (
                <VisitedCountry position={i + 1} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @0stone0. I thought storing them in a state was the proper way to handle them but I see I still have too much React to learn...

Anyway, I did it this way and problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: The problem I´d have now is that you defined the array when creating the component, but my array comes from a fecth so I don´t have that info when creating the component and if not storing the children in a state I don´t know how to update the page... what should I do to handle this @0stone0?

I think this is the reason I started handling this kind of elements in a state, it was the first solution I found to re-render the content after receiving the info

Comment: You should only save the needed data in a state.

Comment: Thanks again, everything working like a charm.